# Computing the density of a set of multiples

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, na.numerical-analysis, computational-number-theory, congruences

Erdős and his coauthors often wrote about problems relating to the densities of sets of multiples. I have a computational question about the same topic. I have a finite* set $A=a_1<\cdots<a_r$ of positive integers. Define $B$ as the set of positive integer multiples of $A$ and
$$
A_1=\frac{1}{a_1}
$$
$$
A_k=\frac{1}{a_k}-\sum_{i<k}\frac{1}{\operatorname{lcm}(a_i,a_k)}+\sum_{i<j<k}\frac{1}{\operatorname{lcm}(a_i,a_j,a_k)}-\cdots.
$$

The density of $B$ is $A_1+\cdots+A_r.$ (If $A$ is infinite the density may not exist, but following the procedure above yields the logarithmic density, which (for sets of multiples) always equals the lower density.)

Is there any practical way to compute the sum above? Naive expansion of the inclusion-exclusion tree yields exponentially many terms. Checking each residue in the LCM is, of course, even worse.

* My set is actually infinite, but I'm lower-bounding the density of its multiples by the density of the multiples of a finite segment. If you can find the density of the set of multiples of an infinite set, this would also answer my question.

---

This is essentially a repost of [the same question on math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1431164/1778), where I offered a bounty but received no answers.

Comment: Since you are actually interested in lower-bounding the density of multiples of an infinite set, I guess you want to fix a positive integer $k$ and thus obtain a lower bound exact up to $k$ decimal digits. In such a case, an idea could be to ignore terms with sufficiently many arguments in the lowest common divisor, since they are small.

Comment: Stevens used (what I call) Bonferroni inequalities to truncate the sum.  Brun did this earlier and with more refinement to get better results.  How practical depends on what you want.  I made small refinements to Stevens's work to get an improved explicit but unoriginal upper bound on Jacobsthal's function (ArXiv 1311.5944, if you're interested).  I think you should try it and see if it works for you.  Gerhard "Got Some Satisfaction From It" Paseman, 2015.09.18